# plot data in connected horizantla lines on python

Tags: python, matplotlib, range

I have these array data x and i want to plot horizantal line for each value in it in a specific sub-interval of the range y
please can any one help me ?

```
x=[2,4,3,5]
;y=np.linspace(0,20,20)
```

[image: The image description]

Comment: I don't really see the relation between the data and the plot. Can you explain?

Comment: each value in the x array represents a horizantla line in certain sub-range in y , do have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with a bit of logic and preparing the x and y coordinates-

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [2, 4, 3, 5]

ys = []
xs = []
step_length = [5, 4, 2, 3]

for i, ycoord in enumerate(y):
    ys.extend([ycoord]*(step_length[i]))
    xs.extend(list(range(len(xs) - i, len(xs) + step_length[i] - i)))
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you , that was realy helpfull, but what if the step_length is not constant, ?

Comment: You can change the step length to an list and index the appropriate one inside the for loop. Give it a try

Comment: i did ,and doesn't retun similiar results, i did somethin like : step_length[i]  with changing the step_length input to a list,

Comment: @ryujiTk check the updated answer and also please update your question